# Deploy from Github to multiple clouds?

Tags: github, heroku, deployment, streamlit

Greetings from Brazil!

I have an app in github which I am deploying to a cloud service. I want to deploy this same app to other services such as Heroku, AWS and/or IBM Cloud, using Github diff changes (i.e. when I update the repo it automatically updates the cloud app - like magic). Currently GitHub diff changes works fine with streamlit share and heroku, but I have separate repos.

**My questions is that: can I deploy an app to multiples services from just one repository in GitHub**?

*Irrelevant for the question: currently the app is Python3 and I share the app in streamlit share and Heroku, using separate repos. My question, however, is app agnostic.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) to define your deployment workflows.

You can deploy to various cloud providers using available actions/operators:

- [Amazon ECS](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/deploying-to-amazon-elastic-container-service)
- [Azure](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/deploying-to-azure-app-service)
- [Heroku](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-heroku)

Your project can define a workflow for each cloud provider and, within each workflow, decide when the deployment occurs (automatically on every push, only selected branches or manually - pushing a button).

Comment: Thank you, @Beppe C, I will look at Actions. Cheers!

Comment: I have a sample repo showing how to do it with Java/Docker if you are interested (see https://github.com/gcatanese/SpringBootService), the same concept applies to Python. Good luck :-)